# Keras convolutional network scoring low on CIFAR-10 Dataset

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, keras

I'm trying to train a CNN on the CIFAR-10 Dataset in Keras, but I'm only getting around 10% accuracy, essentially random. I'm training over 50 epochs, with a batch size of 32 and learning rate of 0.01. Is there anything in particular that I am doing wrong?

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image

from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.utils import np_utils


# trainingData = np.array([np.array(Image.open("train/" + f)) for f in os.listdir("train")]) #shape: 50k, 32, 32, 3
# testingData = np.array([np.array(Image.open("test/" + f)) for f in os.listdir("test")]) #shape: same as training
#
# trainingLabels = np.array(pd.read_csv("trainLabels.csv"))[:,1] #categorical labels ["dog", "cat", "etc"....]
# listOfLabels = sorted(list(set(trainingLabels)))
# trainingOutput = np.array([np.array([1.0 if label == ind else 0.0 for ind in listOfLabels]) for label in trainingLabels]) #converted to output
#                                                                                                                            #for example: training output for dog =
#                                                                                                                                  #[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...]
# np.save("trainingInput.np", trainingData)
# np.save("testingInput.np", testingData)
# np.save("trainingOutput.np", trainingOutput)


trainingInput = np.load("trainingInput.npy") #shape = 50k, 32, 32, 3
testingInput = np.load("testingInput.npy") #shape = 10k, 32, 32, 3

listOfLabels = sorted(list(set(np.array(pd.read_csv("trainLabels.csv"))[:,1]))) #categorical list of labels as strings
trainingOutput = np.load("trainingOutput.npy") #shape = 50k, 10
                                                    #looks like [0.0, 1.0, 0.0 ... 0.0, 0.0]

print(listOfLabels)

print("Data loaded\n______________\n")


inp = Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
conva1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(inp)
conva2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(conva1)
poola = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3))(conva2)
dropa = Dropout(0.1)(poola)

convb1 = Conv2D(128, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='relu')(dropa)
convb2 = Conv2D(128, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='relu')(convb1)
poolb = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3))(convb2)
dropb = Dropout(0.1)(poolb)

flat = Flatten()(dropb)
dropc = Dropout(0.5)(flat)
out = Dense(len(listOfLabels), activation='softmax')(dropc)
print(out.shape)
model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
lrSet = SGD(lr=0.01, clipvalue=0.5)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=lrSet, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(trainingInput, trainingOutput, batch_size=32, epochs=50, verbose=1, validation_split=0.1)
print(model.predict(testingInput))
```

Comment: what kind of accuracy do you get for `model.predict(trainingInput)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anything in particular that I am doing wrong?

Not necessarily "wrong", but some pointers I can suggest are:

1. It is important that you **rescale your data**, in case you are not doing so. Instead of handling values ranging from `[0,255]` it is better to divide all by 255 and handle data with ranges `[0,1]`. This helps your model's weights converge faster, as each gradient update will be more significant compared to it's unscaled version.
2. I think that your **dropout may be affecting your performance**. Even more seeing that you are using CNNs and  a strong (0.5) Dropout when passing data to your output. Quoting [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/317313/161920) great answer:

   > In the **original paper that proposed dropout** layers, by Hinton (2012), dropout (with p=0.5) was used on each of the fully connected **(dense) layers before the output**; it was **not used on the convolutional layers**. This became the most commonly used configuration.
   >
   > More recent research has shown some value in applying **dropout also to convolutional layers, although at much lower levels**: p=0.1 or 0.2.

   So perhaps *reducing your dropout* or playing with it a bit will yield better results. Do notice that you are doing consecutive dropouts on your data, which doesn't seem quite helpful in my opinion and could also be causing problem, so consider redesigning that part:

   ```
   dropb = Dropout(0.1)(poolb) #drop
   flat = Flatten()(dropb) #flatten 
   dropc = Dropout(0.5)(flat) #then drop again?
   ```
3. Your **learning rate may be higher than what is normally used**. Although that is SGD's default learning rate, with higher learning values you may be "rushing" your training and failing to find better minima that could yield better performance. Consider using a *lower learning rate* (`0.001` or lower, adjust epochs as needed), or well adding *weight decay* on your [SGD](https://keras.io/optimizers/#sgd) instance. This will prevent your model from getting stuck on local minima that give sub-optimal results.

Comment: Thanks, all of these suggestions helped! Taking out the second dropout and changing the learning rate fixed it the most.

Comment: @RushilJoshi great to hear that! Glad I could help, good luck with your coding.